# Copy HTML from element, replace text with jQuery, then append to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create portlets on my website which are generated when a user inputs a number and clicks a button.

I have the HTML in a script tag (that way it's invisible). I am able to clone the HTML contents of the script tag and append it to the necessary element without issue. My problem is, I cannot seem to modify the text inside the template before appending it.

This is a super simplified version of what I'd like to do. I'm just trying to get parts of it working properly before building it up more.

Here is the script tag with the template:

```js
var p = $("#tpl_dashboard_portlet").html();
var h = document.createElement('div');
$(h).html(p);
$(h).find('div.m-portlet').data('s', s);
$(h).find('[data-key="number"]').val(s);
$(h).find('[data-key="name"]').val("TEST");
console.log(h);
console.log($(h).html());
console.log(s);
$("div.m-content").append($(h).html());
```

```html
<script id="tpl_dashboard_portlet" type="text/html">
    <!--begin::Portlet-->
    <div class="m-portlet">
        <div class="m-portlet__head">
            <div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
                <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
                    <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text">
                        <span data-key="number"></span> [<span data-key="name"></span>]
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="m-portlet__head-tools">
             <ul class="m-portlet_nav">
              <li class="m-portlet__nav-item">
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="m-portlet__nav-link m-portlet__nav-link--icon"><i class="la la-close"></i></a>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--begin::Form-->
        <div class="m-portlet__body">
         Found! <span data-key="number"></span> [<span data-key="name"></span>]
  </div>
 </div>
    <!--end::Portlet-->
</script>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried using `.each` as well with no luck. Both leave the value of the `span` tags empty.

(I've removed some of the script, but the variable `s` does have a value on it)

Comment: why are you writing html code inside `<script id="tpl_dashboard_portlet" type="text/html">`

Comment: I found it online before and liked the idea. Not really sure what its benefits could/would be for this, apart from not needing to add the hidden attribute. I just went with it and it worked.

Comment: what does `s` contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly, every time you call `$(h)` you're creating a new jQuery object from *the original* template HTML. As such any and all previous changes you made are lost. You need to create the jQuery object from the template HTML *once*, then make all changes to that object.

Secondly, the `span` elements you select by `data-key` attribute do not have `value` properties to change, you instead need to set their `text()`. Try this:

```js
var s = 'foo';
var p = $("#tpl_dashboard_portlet").html();
var $h = $('<div />');
$h.html(p);
$h.find('div.m-portlet').data('s', s);
$h.find('[data-key="number"]').text(s);
$h.find('[data-key="name"]').text("TEST");

$("div.m-content").append($h.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="tpl_dashboard_portlet" type="text/html">
  <div class="m-portlet">
    <div class="m-portlet__head">
      <div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
        <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
          <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text">
            <span data-key="number"></span> [<span data-key="name"></span>]
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-portlet__head-tools">
        <ul class="m-portlet_nav">
          <li class="m-portlet__nav-item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="m-portlet__nav-link m-portlet__nav-link--icon"><i class="la la-close"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="m-portlet__body">
      Found! <span data-key="number"></span> [<span data-key="name"></span>]
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<div class="m-content"></div>
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot now...

The issue was in fact me using `val()` rather than `text()`. Switched it and it's working now.
I never knew that about creating new jQuery elements though. I just saw it done that way on other scripts and have been doing it that way since. I'll have to be sure to not do that going forward.

Thank you for the help though!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case only this is working:

```
var template = $('template').clone(true, true); // Copies all data and events
var $h = $('<div />');
$h.html(template);
$h.find('.input-name').attr('value', "your value here"); // Note: .val("your value here") is not working

$('.list').prepend($h.html());
```